# Deprecated core-js error while installing packages

Tags: node.js, npm, multer, cloudinary, core-js

I am getting this error while trying to install cloudinary and multer-storage-cloudinary:

> npm WARN deprecated core-js@3.6.5: core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling core-js and updated all packages. How to avoid this warning.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an issue with your code, but rather with one of the dependencies of the cloudinary package. This is a known issue (I work in Cloudinary's Developer Support team) and will be addressed in a future update of the cloudinary Node package, but for now it's safe to ignore.

If you have any other issues, you're welcome to raise them to us directly via https://support.cloudinary.com/